# Use ESP8266 as WiFi client connected to Arduino Pro Mini

Tags: wifi, esp8266, softwareserial, arduino-pro-mini, software

So i'm trying to use the [PubSubClient Library](https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient) on my arduino mini pro, but I'm connecting to the internet via wifi using an ESP8266.

Using a mini means I have to use software serial to connect to the ESP, but I've ran into a problem. I can't find anywhere such as `ESPWiFiClient` to use with the examples from the PubSubClient library where they use `EthernetClient`.

Is there any available libraries that can emulate EthernetClient with an ESP module over software serial?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for using the pubsubclient library? There are other mqtt libraries out there which do work with the esp8266... I do however completely agree with the answer below that ditching your Arduino and uploading the Arduino code to your ESP8266 is a much better approach.

Answer (score 1):

Ditch the Pro Mini.  Upload your Arduino code to the ESP directly. There's a GitHub repo with the details. ESP for Arduino IDE has a ton of libraries. I'm sure you'll find it there.

But if you're bent on using the Pro Mini,  you'll have to use AT commands over serial to control it or flash a custom firmware into the ESP using Lua or something. And Pro Mini can use its hardware serial just like a Uno does.